# How to handle changes in class structure and be backward compatible with data/objects serialized using boost?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have the task of adding members to a c++ class that uses

```
boost::serialization::access
```

The objects are stored to text files and read back in.

However, I need to be backward compatible and the new bool member must be serialized.

I need to allow the new code to read the old files and write only the new format.

Specifically the serialized files are missing the new data member.  This causes an exception when reading in.

How can I do this?/What suggestions/mechanisms allow this to happen?

I would imagine there is a pattern or known way of handling this and I am not sure what that might be.

(Surely the folks writing the boost code understood that code/objects will change and the older files have to be handled by new code/object)

Comment: This is what the `version` argument is for -- for _you_ to version your own objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost's serialization supports versions. See the following links: [Link #1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning), [Link #2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#version) and an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp).