# Can boost::serialization::access dynamically change versions at run time/programatically?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589278/how-to-handle-changes-in-class-structure-and-be-backward-compatible-with-data-ob) about how to make "versioned" serializaion using `boost::serialization::access`

I have been able to do some of what I want, but there seem to be significant limitations.

Specifically, I would like to be able to change the versions at run time and change the serialization version dynamically in the code.

However, the macro

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(ClassName, ver)
```

seems not to allow this type of behavior.

I suppose I could make different classes and use them each when I need each, but I would prefer not to since that requires a lot of code changes for us.

**Is there a way to programmatically change the class to use different versions during the same execution?**

A little more explanation of what we need to do:

The use case I am trying to work with is the program reading in the old version (when it is first run/upgraded), then writing with the NEW version and then also being able to read that NEW version.

Comment: have you looked at the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning) (provided by your referenced question)? it gives the example of a bus_route class, checking the version before loading the new field. the [demo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp) illustrates the same thing

Comment: @Hasturkun yes, I have but that does not allow different versions in same execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design appears to intend that you do not change the version dynamically. Supporting the reading of old data is however possible via the *version* parameter to your *serialize*, *save*, or *load* functions.  That is, in your loading function you can check the *version* and see if particular parts have to be loaded differently. So loading old data is possible, but it has to be done within one set of serialization functions.

Comment: I don't understand how to change that parameter during execution.  I only see how to set it statically at compile time.  Is there an example of how to do this?

Comment: When its reading from the old data the version number passed to the function will be the one stored in the file, not the static one.